# Running Background task for checking regular updates python-flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have one web application with Rest API ,In that application I have some video files now i am creating one intermediate server in this one.I am accessing my web content using API  but here i need to check updates in regular intervals if new updates will be there i need to download them.
Here files are video files and i'm using flask 
I tried this i'm not getting

```html
from flask import Flask,render_template,json,jsonify
import schedule
import time
import requests,json
from pathlib import Path
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
import schedule,wget,requests,json,os,errno,shutil,time,config

def get_videos():
 response = requests.get('my api here')
 data = response.json() 
 files =list() # collecting my list of video files 
 l = len(data)
 for i in range(l):
  files.append(data[i]['filename'])
 return files

def checkfor_file(myfiles):
 for i in range(len(myfiles)):
  url = 'http://website.com/static/Video/'+myfiles[i] # checking file exists are not in my folder
  if url:
   os.remove(url)
  else:
   pass
def get_newfiles(myfiles):
 for i in range(len(myfiles)):
  url = config.videos+myfiles[i] 
  filename= wget.download(url)# downloading video files here
def move_files(myfiles):
 for i in range(len(myfiles)):
  file = myfiles[i]
  shutil.move(config.source_files+file,config.destinatin) # moving download folder to another folder
def videos():
 files = set(get_videos()) # getting only unique file only 
 myfiles = list(files)
 checkfor_file(myfiles)
 get_newfiles(myfiles)
 move_files(myfiles)
def job():
 videos()

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job) # running for every ten minutes
while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)



pi =Flask(__name__)
@pi.route('/')
def index():
 response = requests.get('myapi')
 data = response.json()
 return render_template('main.html',data=data)
```